# How should we think about the relationship between left and right eigenvectors of a row stochastic matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

I am considering row stochastic matrices, i.e. those for which the rows sum up to one.

In particular, I am trying to understand the conceptual difference between the left and right eigenvectors of such matrices. It is clear to me that the left eigenvectors represent any stable and metastable states of the Markov chain. And in general, for multiplying a probability row vector from the left, I understand that P acts generates the evolution of this distribution one step into the future.

However, for right eigenvectors this is less clear. This previous post gave some good insight: [Use and interpretation of the first and second right eigenvectors of a right Markov matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1360943/) but I haven't managed to find a standard textbook on Markov Chains explain this in any depth. In Levin and Peris, this is only mentioned very briefly at the end of section 1.1. Does anyone know any text that explain the relationship of left and right eigenvectors?